# How to remove hacker message from magento website and how to create a good security for magento website

Tags: magento-1.7, core-hacks

How to remove hacker message from magento website and how to create a good security for magento website. my website is borsavela.com. how to fix it.

Comment: do you have any backup ?

Comment: yes i have backup in my pc which file replace for previous look ...

Comment: if you took backup recently and if you are ready to go with that than you can revert to previous backup and than check your site : http://magereport.com/  and follow all security steps mentioned in that site

Comment: one more tip : as hackers already attacked now its better to restrict the site only to your i.p using `.htaccess` file.

Comment: am trying to update files one by one i m using magento 1.7.0.2 can i update latest security patch in this version. currently can you give me suggestion which files replace for clear hack messages in shortcut because i have many files in this websites

Comment: may be [this link](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=m8jfV5OlCcWL8QfltbigBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento+remove+hacking) will help better.....

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to upgrade the version to 1.9.2.4 and also competeble all extensions with SUPPEE-6788.

This patch was introduce for security reason from Magento itself.

And need to remove code from the admin header and footer miscellaneous code.

Hope this will help you.
Thanks

Comment: which template file affected by hacker in this sichuation ?? how can easily remove it.

Comment: They using script for it so please upgrade to newer version.

Answer (score 0):

It happens, now first thing you need to do is restrict your site to be access only through your IP using .htaccess file.

take backup of .htaccess file and add this below code in .htaccess

credits :**[TBI Infotech](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/6451/tbi-infotech)** for [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21349/how-to-restrict-specfic-ip-address-to-access-magento-site-in-htaccess-file-in-m)

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

There are lot of resources available to remove [hacking code here](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=m8jfV5OlCcWL8QfltbigBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento+remove+hacking) , if that did't works for you,

next thing is as you said you have backup , than revert to previous backup. than scan you site in [Magereport](https://www.magereport.com/) . there they will mention to install required security patches and changing **admin and magento connect url** . once you install security patches , than lot of 3 -party extensions feature may break down. you need to contact extension team to provide  updated extensions that supports security features.

or if you **don't have any 3-part modules** , if you did't done any **core files edit** [ also if you are struggling to install all security patches ]  , than upgrade to 1.9.2.4 version

Answer (score 0):

My points on your issue list is never ending

1. Rename the admin router your admin panel should not easily accessible by just `base_url/admin` so please rename your admin URL
2. Admin username **should not** be `admin`
3. Update your website to Magento new release 1.9.2.4
4. Apply all security patches resales by Magento (check [here](http://magereport.com/)  )
5. Give proper permission to directory and files (note: please do not give write permission unnecessary )
6. Restrict your admin URL by IP address so other random users cannot able to reach your admin URL, for this you can use [this](https://shop.etwebsolutions.com/eng/et-ip-security.html) extension

manage your code via bitbucket or any versing control system so you can revert your changes any day.

though the list is never ending but you can take above issue

Comment: Bhai, magento connect is not exist now

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara OK extension url updated